# Input tag's placeholder and cursor are not vertically center

Tags: html, css, input, cursor, placeholder

I'm facing an issue with **vertically centering** the **placeholder** and **cursor** in an **input field**. This issue specifically occurs in the **Chrome browser**, while it works fine in **Firefox**. How can I resolve this problem and ensure consistent vertical alignment across **different browsers**?

**`HTML`**

```
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="Search term label"
      className={cx('search-header__input')}
    />
```

**`CSS`**

```
.search-header__input {
  border: none;
  width: 80%;
  height: rem(24px);

  &:focus {
    outline: none;
  }
}
```

**`my problem is`**

[image]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Code so far doesn't appear to really reproduce the issue, https://jsfiddle.net/jhest2g6/ - so please show a proper [mre] of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `flex` and `align-items: center` :

```css
.search-header__input {
  border: none;
  width: 80%;
  height: rem(24px);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  
  &:focus {
    outline: none;
  }
}
```

```html
  <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="Search term label"
      className="search-header__input"
    />
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice @Johan. But this doesn't work for me. If you have any other suggestions please share.

Comment: How is it in other browsers ?

Comment: Its works fine Firefox. But Not working properly in Chrome and Brave browser.

Comment: So it does not comes from your CSS. Try to find maybe some Webkits